# Sort a FormArray by Boolean property

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a FormArray which I push with a formgroup. I want to sort this FormArray using isAM attribute (isAM is a Boolean), so that when displaying the ones having isAM true are displayed first

```
let identifiersControl: FormArray = <FormArray>this.editOrganizationForm.controls['identifiers'];

organization.identifiers.forEach(identifier => {
   identifiersControl.push(this.fb.group({
         typeIdentifier: this.fb.group({ id: identifier.typeIdentifier.id }),
         numIdentifier: identifier.numIdentifier,
         isAM: [identifier.isAM]
   }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#patchValue-usage-notes) can be used to update the initial formArray

```
this.identifiersControl.push(this.fb.group({
         typeIdentifier: this.fb.group({ id: identifier.typeIdentifier.id }),
         numIdentifier: identifier.numIdentifier,
         isAM: [identifier.isAM]
   }))

let array = identifiersControl.value

array.sort((a, b) => a.isAM < b.isAm)

identifiersControl.patchValue(array)
```

live code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sort-angular-form)

Comment: Are you sure? sort must return value greater 0, less 0 or 0. it's must be array.sort((a,b)=>a && !b?1:!a && b:-1:0)

Comment: @Eliseo, there is no need if the comparison is to be performed on a boolean property